# Unzip using libz.dylib

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, unzip, ios-frameworks

I have read that unzip can be done using libz.dylib library. But I am not able to find out how to do it. I am using ZipArchive to extract the files now. But still I just want to use the default framework provided by apple.
Can we can do unzip operation using libz.dylib ? or is there any problem ?

Comment: You should probably search in google to find the solution. 

check this link: http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Below Code

1) Download ZipArchive from [Link for ZipArchive API](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list.)

2) Drag into project.

3) Add to project existing framework libz.1.2.3.dylib (last version).

Import `#import "ZipArchive.h"` header in your ViewController

```
 ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    if ([za UnzipOpenFile: filePathToUnzip]) {
               BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:filePathtoBePlacedAfterUnzip overWrite: YES];
    if(ret)
 //unzipSuceesfully.

 else
 //Failed to Unzip.

             [za UnzipCloseFile];
   }
[za release];
```

Comment: Hi. Please note that I have mentioned that I have used ZipArchive in my project. The ZipArchive is a third party right ?